# django listing files instead of showing home page

Tags: python, django

I'm not able to figure out what's going wrong. I'm using pycharm and bitnami django stack for developing my first web application.

Here is my directory structure:

project name: myapp

location: C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7.8-0\apache2\htdocs\myapp

### Directory structure:

```
myapp
    manage.py
    app
          admin.py
          models.py
          settings.py
          tests.py
          urls.py
          views.py
          wsgi.py

          migrations
    templates
          home.html
```

### my settings.py has following data:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

### my urls.py has following data:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'myapp/', views.homepage, name='home'),
]
```

### my views.py has following data:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

Now when I try to run:

http://localhost/myapp

It simply displays the list of files in the myapp directory

I'm not able to find why it is not executing from urls.py

Comment: Are you running the django development server or Apache?

Comment: apache, bitnami django stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your app up and running with Apache, you will have to enable reverse-proxying.

To do this, you can try adding the following lines to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`, supposing that your application `myapp` is running at port 8000:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8000/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8000/myapp
```

To make sure that the `mod_proxy` module is enabled, please find the following lines and uncomment them:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

Finally, after saving the changes you can proceed to restart Apache:

```
/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You should now be able to access your application in: http://localhost/myapp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I guess your suggestion says that I have to start both development server and apache server.
I want to run my app like we do with PHP in wampp.

Comment: In this case, you would have to use something like WSGI with Apache mod_wsgi. You can check how this is done in other [Bitnami Python stacks](https://bitnami.com/tag/python) or [follow this guide in the Bitnami Wiki for Django](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Django#How_to_start_a_Django_project.3f) to configure WSGI. This is the recommended setup for production environments.

Comment: For others, make sure that "installdir" is a proper path like C:/Bitnami/djangostack-1.7.8-0

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to run the project with the development server. In Pycharm, I went to Tools -> Run manage.py Task -> run server

And then executed the url:

http://localhost:8000/myapp/

But still trying to figure out why it is not running with apache in Bitnami stack